# Доступ к приватном конструктору создаваемого объекта из std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Хотел написать простенький контейнер/фабрику и запретить создание объекта иными способами, но столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой.
Упрощенный код:

```
struct MyObject
{
    friend struct MyObjectContainer;
private:
    MyObject(int param) { _param = param; }
    int _param;
};

struct MyObjectContainer : private std::vector<MyObject>
{
    void Add(int param) { emplace_back(param); }
} objs;
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   14.0\vc\include\xmemory0(637): error C2248: 'MyObject::MyObject': cannot access private member declared in class 'MyObject'

При замене **emplace_back(param)** на **push_back(MyObject(param))** код работает, но хотелось бы найти способ использовать более рациональный метод emplace_back.

Comment: почему MyObjectContainer френд для MyObject? Почему конструктор приватный? Вы и вектор отнаследовали приватом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо прописать friend для std::allocator, т.к. именно этот шаблон создаёт ваш класс.

```
struct MyObject
{
friend class std::allocator<MyObject>;
...
```

Comment: Тогда не имеет смысла использовать emplace_back, так как проще будет написать push_back, как это уже указано в вопросе.

Comment: ну так для `MyObject` дружественен `MyObjectContainer` а не вектор. Такая избыточная закрытость породит для кода больше проблем.

Comment: Ваше решение не работает под gcc. Там нужно писать что-то типа `friend class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<MyObject>;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вариант рабочий (так же подошел для std::queue и std::deque). А вот с std::list и std::forward_list, к сожалению, не компилируется (пишет ту же ошибку), может знаете, как победить? )

Comment: @AlekseySokolov компилятор Вам должен написать какой класс пытается вызвать приватный конструктор. *clang* например, сказал следующее: `std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__list_node<MyObject, void *> >`. Но это всё очень криво, хотя и делает код компилябельным. Я рекомендую не создавать проблем на ровном месте. Подход из моего ответа успешно работает для любых типов стандартных контейнеров.

Comment: Вообще может вам задуматься о собственном аллокаторе для таких контейнеров, чтобы он и создавал этот объект.

Answer (score 3):

Если к `MyObject` доступ есть только у `MyObjectContainer`, то логичнее его просто сделать вложенным классом в *private*-секции. Заодно наследование заменить агрегированием:

```
struct MyObjectContainer 
{
    void Add(int param) { 
        v.emplace_back(param); 
    }
private:
    struct MyObject
    {
        MyObject(int param) { _param = param; }
        int _param;
    };    
    std::vector<MyObject> v;   
} objs;
```